# Mostrar dados array

Tags: php, array

Tenho os seguintes dados obtidos de uma consulta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ler esses dados e mostrar na tela,  porem, primeiro mostrar todas as metas, depois mostrar todos desafios e assim por diante.

```html
<?php 

$resultado = ibase_query($CONEXAO_TERM, QueryDashGraf1(substr($loja_selecionada, 0,3),$data_dash, $data_inicial,$ultimo_dia_f));//executa query e armazena o resultado em um array

while ($dash = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
 echo trim($dash['0']);
   
}
while ($dash = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
 echo trim($dash['3']);

}
?>
```

Fazendo dessa forma, o segundo While não é mostrado.

Como faço para que os dados apareçam corretamente na tela?

Comment: Eu não to conseguindo entender o que você quer tem como explicar melhor ?

Comment: Eu acho que entendi, você quer listar os valores na ordem DSMTE, DSDESAFIO, isso em linhas, por exemplo listar todos os DSMETA, depois listar todos os DSDESAFIO?

Comment: Exatamente ... no primeiro Whilelistar todos DSMETA, no segundo While listar todos DSDESAFIO,  e assim por diante.

Comment: Do jeito que esta ele lista somente os dados do primeiro While no caso os DSMETA.

Comment: Vou responder um teste me fala o resultado dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse exemplo eu to criando um vetor bi dimensional, onde a chave é coluna e o valor é um array de valores das colunas depois eu imprimo tudo. no caso e só um teste, depois é só adequar a seu caso.

```
<?php 

$resultado = ibase_query($CONEXAO_TERM, QueryDashGraf1(substr($loja_selecionada, 0,3),$data_dash, $data_inicial,$ultimo_dia_f));//executa query e armazena o resultado em um array

while ($dash = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
    foreach ($dash as $key => $value) {
        $array_return[$key][] = $value;
    }

}
foreach ($array_return as $key => $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
        echo trim($value);
    }
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algumas dúvidas: Tem um foreach dentro do while  e outro fora, quais as funções deles??

Comment: O primeiro while eu percorro cada linha, o foreach eu percorro cada item da linha criando um vetor, de forma que todos os valores de DSMETA, vão ficar no vetor, por exemplo: `$array_return[''DSMETA][0] = 500,000,000`, e assim por diante. funcionou ?ou retornou erro ?

Comment: Coloquei minha linha assim: $array_return['PERIODO'][0] = $dash[3]; supondo que eu queira listar os periodos. Desta forma listou apenas um dado.

Comment: se que assim, não tem que colocar o `[0]` assim ele irá atribuir uma nova posição para cada o certo seria apenas `$array_return['PERIODO'][] = $dash[3];`. você conseguiu entender a lógica do que fiz e isso retornou algo ? como não tenho acesso ao banco e mais complicado.

Comment: Se eu colocar dessa forma $array_return[$key][0] = $dash[3];    retorna 2018/092018/092018/092018/09.  Gostaria que aparecesse todos valores do DSPERIODO.

Comment: você só quer os valores de DSPERIODO ?

Comment: Na primeira passada sim ....depois fazer outro while  só com valores do DSMETA  e assim por diante

Comment: me faz um favor, baixo do primeiro while colocar isso aqui 
`echo "<pre>"; var_dump($array_return); ` e tira um print e cola o link aqui.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88365/discussion-between-alexandre-prezzi-and-bulfaitelo).

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei no final o print